# VSTS - Error APPX0105: Cannot import the key file 'blah.pfx'. The key file may be password protected

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-devops

This is a VSTS question and not to be confused with similar questions asked before. This application does not use strong name.
I have a WIN RT legacy project and the certificate has run out.
So I have a new one and I have set the password and put it in my project.
However when I run the VSTS build I get the following error messages.



> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets
>   (2557, 5)     C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2557,5):
>   Error APPX0105: Cannot import the key file
>   'blah.pfx'. The key file may be password protected.
>   To correct this, try to import the certificate manually into the
>   current user's personal certificate store.
>
> 
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets
>   (2557, 5)     C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2557,5):
>   Error APPX0102: A certificate with thumbprint
>   '11F4B2DBB13F0BDACAEA79617C76279AAB394592' that is specified in the
>   project cannot be found in the certificate store. Please specify a
>   valid thumbprint in the project file.
>
> 
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets
>   (2557, 5)     C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2557,5):
>   Error APPX0107: The certificate specified is not valid for signing.
>   For more information about valid certificates, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478.
>
>    Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

How do I fix this?

EDIT. I tried running the powershell command but I got this response;
[image]

Comment: "I have set the password" => The key file may be password protected

Answer (score 1):

From the last error trace:

> The certificate specified is **not valid for signing**

I expect that certificate is a [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate), in that case you can take a look on [this Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/certificate?view=tfs-2018) to
Run the agent with self-signed certificate.

---

From the first error trace:

> **try to import the certificate manually** into the current user's personal certificate store.

It is also possible that you did not install the certificate in the machine certificate store. please refer the the [same link in that case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/certificate?view=tfs-2018).

---

You can doublecheck whether the certificate has been installed correctly by running this command:

```
PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://corp.tfs.com/tfs -UseDefaultCredentials
```

---

You may also get useful information on "Support Ssl Client Certificate in Build/Release Job" [in this page](http://PowerShell%20Invoke-WebRequest%20-Uri%20https://corp.tfs.com/tfs%20-UseDefaultCredentials)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not understand the documentation you pointed me towards. The last link appears to be broken. The first link to the MS documentation shows a prompt of "Enter server URL" but does not explain how to get there.

Comment: Also when I run the command above in powershell I get "invoke-webrequest : The remote name could not be resolved: 'corp.tfs.com'". See image in the question.

Comment: Your first deduction is not correct. Because of the earlier errors, the last error occurs. This happens even with proper signed certificates, if the import fails.